# How to return an error from a function that returns signed integers

Tags: c++

I have some psuedocode for a function to display a value and get a value

```
int getValue(){
    int value;
    // open file
    // read line into "value"
    if(error occurs){ 
        // if file doesn't open or line was not an integer
        /* Normally I would return something such as -1
           but -1 in this case would be a valid value*/
        value = ?
    }
    return value;
}

void displayValue(){
    int value = getValue();
    if(value is valid)
         display(value);
}
```

As described in the code above, I would like to return that there was an error and let *displayValue* know that there was an error. But i want to accept negative,positive, and 0 from getValue.

Is there a better way to go about this? Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: `std::pair<bool, int>`?

Comment: You have an exceptional condition, throw an exception? This isn't C, exceptions are a thing.

Comment: If you need the function signature to remain the same, then use `exceptions` instead.

Comment: If the entire range of values for your function is possible, than there is no value you can return to signal an error. You need an alternative solution. Maybe throw an exception. Maybe change the return type. Maybe return an `optional<int>` instead. It depends on how you want the function to be used and how "exceptional" you consider errors to be.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It isn't clear that these errors are exceptional conditions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If it's a legit error (bad file data of some form), that's almost always exceptional.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Maybe, but you're assuming the nature of the error.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Umm... I'm reading the comments in the example code. The problem is an unopenable file, or bad data (non-integer, when integer expected). No assumptions needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throw an exception. One of the advantages of C++ over C is that, when you have an error, you don't have to smuggle error codes out of the function, you can just `throw` an exception. If it's a truly exceptional case, most of the time the caller won't have anything useful to do with it anyway, so forcing them to check for it manually, then pass the error up the call chain is pointless. If they *do* know what to do with it, they can `catch` it.

This solution is also more composable. Imagine a scenario where `A` returns `int`, `B` calls `A` and returns a `std::string` based on it, and `C` calls `B` and returns class `Foo` based on that. If `A` has an exceptional condition that requires it to return an error, you can either:

1. Come up with some way to smuggle the error out of `A` as an `int` (or `std::optional<int>` or `std::pair<bool, int>` or whatever), then check for and convert that smuggled error to a different smuggled error for `B`, then check for and convert that to yet another smuggled error for `C`, then the caller of `C` still needs to check for that smuggled error *and* all three layers have to pay the price of the checks *every* time, even when all three layers *succeeded*, or...
2. You `throw` an exception in `A`, neither `B` nor `C` have anything useful to do with it (so they don't write any additional code at all), and the caller of `C` can choose to `catch` the exception and produce a friendlier error message if they so choose.

On modern architectures, the cost in the success case for #2 should be pretty negligible; the failure case might be more costly than the "check at every level case", but for something like "file doesn't exist" or "file contains corrupt data", it hardly matters if performance suffers, since you're probably about to exit the program (so speed doesn't count) or pop a dialog the user needs to respond to (the user is slower than the computer by many orders of magnitude).

Comment: Thank you, I should have known to do this

Comment: @Daniel: No problem. There is absolutely a tendency for those coming from non-C++ languages with (relatively) cheap exceptions (e.g. Python, where `try`/`except` is only slightly more expensive than an `if` statement) to *overuse* exceptions in non-exceptional cases, and doing so *can* hurt performance, so it's okay to be leery of throwing exceptions when it's not necessary (e.g. don't use exceptions for membership testing where both presence or absence of the element in question is considered a normalish outcome), but your specific use case is very much the ideal scenario for exceptions.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Sadly I've been a c++ developer for 4 years now but after dealing with so much legacy code and trying to get products out the door, I seem to have forgotten how to code properly :(

Answer (score 4):

There are several error handling approaches in C++:

The traditional way popular in C API's (also used by `std::string` algorithms) is to reserve at least one value as "invalid", which when returned would signal that there was an error, or that the value represents "no result". In case of error, the C API's would use the global `errno` to inform what error happened.

One of the features C++ introduced over the C language is exceptions. You can simply throw when error occurs. This is most appropriate for unexpected errors or pre/post-condition violations, rather than "no result exists" type situations.

Yet another way is to return both the value, and information about whether the result is valid. Old fashioned approach might be to return a pair of integer and boolean (or a named class that achieves the same). Alternatively, either value or error state can written into object passed through indirection. `std::optional` has been introduced into the standard library just for this kind of situation an is a great way of representing lack of result.

Latter approach can be further extended to not only return a boolean, but actual information about the error in similar way to the way exceptions do. The error information can also be wrapped with the value in a "variant" type so that they can share the space, as only one of them can exist at any time. This approach is similar to `Maybe` type in Haskell. There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/SC22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0323r7.html) to introduce a template for this purpose into the standard library.

Each of these approaches have their benefits and drawbacks. Choose one that is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Not really C++ specific, but CPython (which is limited to C-style error handling) uses the "reserved" value approach without actually reserving it in most cases; many APIs that can return any `int` return `-1` for an error, but it's only *really* an error if `PyErr_Occurred()` returns a truthy value. A similar approach could be used in C++ if absolutely necessary, where, say, a return of `-1` is used for errors, but `errno` is only set to a non-`0` value if an error actually occurred, and callers check for an error by checking `if (retval == -1 && errno != 0)` or the like. Not recommending it.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to throw an exception when an error occurs. It's highly dependent on the rest of your project. Are Exceptions used all around ? Personally, I prefer more conventional old-school approaches. Mostly because people will start throwing exception everywhere, where it's not really exceptional and then it makes debugging much harder as the debugger keeps stopping for non-exceptional situations.

Another option is to return a pair `std::pair<bool, int>`. Some people love it, some people hate it.

My preference would be `bool attemptGetValue(int& outValue)`. You return false if there's an error, in which case you don't touch `outValue`. Your return true otherwise and modify `outValue`

You can also use `std::optional`, but old timers might not be familiar wiht it.

Comment: Old timers might not be as familiar with `std::optional` but that is their problem. `std::optional` clearly self-documents the intention, there is no need to interpret the meaning of the `bool` in the pair.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've been exposed to a wide variety of code styles in my professional life. And the best, most solid, most maintainable was something in plain old C (in am otherwise C++ project). At first I hated it, but in the long-run, using less bells and whistles makes for simple, easy-to-maintain, less buggy code. Your mileage will vary, but I want to show the option.

Comment: It seems you think `std::optional` is more "bells and whistles" than `std::pair`. Could you please elaborate? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: `std::pair<bool, T>` is used in the `std::map` interface for certain functions. That justifies its use in my book.

Comment: From most bell-and-whistles to least, IMO:  'optional', 'exception', 'pair', 'bool and ref'. But hey, it's a style spectrum

Comment: @Bathsheba That's an interesting point. But in that case, the `bool` doesn't indicate the validity of the associated `iterator`. So that use case is not compatible with `std::optional` so there is not a great comparison for the two. It actually goes to show one problem with using the wider interface of `std::pair` over `std::optional` when both work. The meaning for the elements of `std::pair` are more open to interpretation. It takes more effort to reason about it.

Comment: @Jeffrey What I was actually wondering is where that ordering comes from. What are the metrics or characteristics used to determine that? Is it just a gut feeling and personal preference?

Answer (score 2):

Other than throwing an exception, returning a `std::optional`, or a `std::pair`, there is a precedent here: `std::string::npos` is normally set to a particularly large `std::string::size_type` value, normally `-1` (wrapped around of course) and is used by some `std::string` functions to indicate a failure.

If you're willing to give up one legitimate return value then you could do something similar in your case. In reality though, typical (perhaps all) strings will be significantly smaller than `npos`; if that's not the case for you then perhaps one of the alternatives already mentioned would be better.

Comment: OP specifically wants the full range of values for `int` to be usable. This solution may be applicable, but a larger type needs to be returned. But then the result likely has to be cast. This is similar to how many `iostream` and `char` related standard features deal in `int`s to handle special values like `EOF` instead of directly handling character types.